# Python Exe Obfuscation to Evade Windows Defender

Tags: python, windows, obfuscation, malware-detection

I know this sounds kind of shady but let me explain.

I wrote a program in Python to automate some tasks for my work. Now, when I try to build the project into an EXE and run it on my Windows machine, Windows Defender recognizes it as malware and removes it. I don't want to buy any licenses or contact support.

What would be an efficient way to obfuscate my code and get it through Windows Defender?

I got a whole project folder with multiple scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say the easier way to go about it would be to exclude the file from Windows Defender on your machine, see [Windows Support thread on this.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Update,%2C%20file%20types%2C%20or%20process.)

You may exclude the entire project folder from Defender, should probably solve your problem?